# Specifying 'title' attrib to style sheet doesn't allow it to be applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code that works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var style = $('#formulario').val();

  $('#formulario').change(function() {
    var nombreArchivo = $(this).val();
    nombreArchivo = nombreArchivo.replace(/ /gi, '_');
    var ruta = '/printbox/views/formulariosweb/';
    $('#contenedorFormulario').load( ruta + nombreArchivo + '.html');
    $('head').append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>').attr('href', ruta + nombreArchivo + '.css') );
  });

  $("#formulario").trigger('change');

});
```

It changes a div's content based on the selection in a form, and the style is being applied correctly on each change.

However, it adds the css as many times as I change the value in the form.

The problem comes when I try to set a `title` attribute to the `LINK`, then only the first style works, and when I change it, the new style is loaded into the `head` but not being applied.

I went to W3 web (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp) and it says that LINK supports the attribute `title`, so I don't know whats wrong here. I add it this way:

```
$('head').append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>').attr({ 'href': ruta + nombreArchivo + '.css', 'title': nombreArchivo }) );
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

PS: I add title attribute to be able to identify and remove it later, once I change the value in the dropdown list, so it doesn't populate the header.

Comment: Where did you see that `link` supports `title`? I didn't see anything about that in W3Schools. Also, why would you use that?

Comment: @vcampitelli Global Attributes

The <link> tag also supports the Global Attributes in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to report this issue to Mozilla bugtrack and found a similar issue (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=223410) where this is discussed, and led me to this page:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.3.1

where the specification says that specifying `title` attribute makes it preferred style, and then no other styles are applied.

```
Authors may specify a number of mutually exclusive style sheets called alternate style sheets. Users may select their favorite among these depending on their preferences.
For instance, an author may specify one style sheet designed for small screens and another for users with weak vision (e.g., large fonts).
User agents should allow users to select from alternate style sheets.

The author may specify that one of the alternates is a preferred style sheet. User agents should apply the author's preferred style sheet unless the user has selected a different alternate.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the stylesheet isn't already loaded using the following:

```
if (!$("link[href='/path/to.css']").length)
```

So, if the goal is ultimately that you only want to load each style sheet once, then your code would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var style = $('#formulario').val();

  $('#formulario').change(function() {
    var nombreArchivo = $(this).val();
    nombreArchivo = nombreArchivo.replace(/ /gi, '_');
    var ruta = '/printbox/views/formulariosweb/';
    $('#contenedorFormulario').load( ruta + nombreArchivo + '.html');
    if (!$("link[href='" + ruta + nombreArchivo + "'.css']").length) {
      $('head').append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>').attr('href', ruta + nombreArchivo + '.css') );
    }
 });

 $("#formulario").trigger('change');

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Blake, I have found that it might be a bug with `title` attribute because I changed it to use `id` instead and works as expected, I already have a way to load only one at a time using jquery's `remove`.